Any mixer like MG12XU with multitrack USB output?
I have been looking for a solution that can take multiple channels and feed it over USB to my computer (Like an interface). I want the sound quality to be great over the USB, since that is the only mode of recording I would use.
My main requirements are

Multitrack USB recording, as in 10 channel in, 10 channel USB out.
I need a minimum of 10 channels, and with all the functionality of the Yamaha MG12XU mixer, like FX, channels with comp, pad & HFL, phantom power, etc. Faders would be great.
I need the several effects as on the Yamaha MG12XU, and apart from that, it would be great to have multiple effects applied at once, and different effects for different channels.
I want the price to be close to that of the Yamaha MG12XU.
It should be available in India.

Is there any good quality device that satisfies the above requirements?

You can check BEHRINGER XR12, but it is entirely digital, you need tablet to manage it
